# Extracting meta analysis estimate and CI from output in R

Tags: r, object

```
library(meta)
m1 <- metaprop(4:1, c(10, 20, 30, 40))
m2 <- update(m1, sm="PAS")
m3 <- update(m1, sm="PRAW")
m4 <- update(m1, sm="PLN")
m5 <- update(m1, sm="PFT")
#
forest(m5)
```

[image]
I have a simple example here, and I want to extract the random estimate of the effect and its corresponding 95% CI (i.e. 0.11[ 0.01; 0.26] as shown in the picture).

I used `names(m5)` to see a list of values. And I've tried `m5$lower.random` in hopes of getting the lower CI bound for the random effects model, but the returned value is 0.1837517 instead of 0.01, which is what's presented in the forest plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the proportion estimated by the random effects models (with 95% confidence intervals),  the `m5$TE.random`, `m5$lower.random` and `m5$upper.random` values need to be backtransformed according to the `sm` option specified in `metaprop`.
Let consider a first case where the logit transformation was chosen to calculate an overall proportion:

```
library(meta) 
m1 <- metaprop(4:1, c(10, 20, 30, 40), sm="PLOGIT")
summary(m1)

################
Number of studies combined: k = 4

                     proportion           95%-CI  z  p-value
Fixed effect model       0.1439 [0.0769; 0.2533] --       --
Random effects model     0.1214 [0.0373; 0.3306] --       --

Quantifying heterogeneity:
 tau^2 = 1.1288; H = 1.77 [1.04; 3.01]; I^2 = 68.0% [7.1%; 89.0%]

Test of heterogeneity:
    Q d.f.  p-value
 9.38    3   0.0247

Details on meta-analytical method:
- Inverse variance method
- DerSimonian-Laird estimator for tau^2
- Logit transformation
- Clopper-Pearson confidence interval for individual studies

    (random.est1 <- c(m1$TE.random,m1$lower.random,m1$upper.random))
    meta:::backtransf(random.est1, sm="PLOGIT")
    meta:::logit2p(random.est1)
################
```

We extract from `m1` the trasformed values of the random effect model:

```
(random.est1 <- c(m1$TE.random,m1$lower.random,m1$upper.random))

###############
[1] -1.9788316 -3.2521123 -0.7055509
```

and then we backtransform using the `meta:::backtransf` function of `meta`

```
meta:::backtransf(random.est1, sm="PLOGIT")
#######
[1] 0.12144344 0.03725106 0.33058266
```

or directly the logit backtransformation `logit2p`:

```
meta:::logit2p(random.est1)
#######
[1] 0.12144344 0.03725106 0.33058266
```

which is equivalent to:

```
plogis(random.est1)
#######
[1] 0.12144344 0.03725106 0.33058266
```

Now we consider a second example using the Freeman-Tukey Double arcsine transformation:

```
m2 <- metaprop(4:1, c(10, 20, 30, 40), sm="PFT")
summary(m2)

###################
Number of studies combined: k = 4

                     proportion           95%-CI  z  p-value
Fixed effect model       0.0775 [0.0272; 0.1449] --       --
Random effects model     0.1093 [0.0138; 0.2589] --       --

Quantifying heterogeneity:
 tau^2 = 0.0229; H = 1.78 [1.05; 3.04]; I^2 = 68.6% [9.1%; 89.2%]

Test of heterogeneity:
    Q d.f.  p-value
 9.56    3   0.0227

Details on meta-analytical method:
- Inverse variance method
- DerSimonian-Laird estimator for tau^2
- Freeman-Tukey double arcsine transformation
- Clopper-Pearson confidence interval for individual studies
###################
```

Using the backtrasformation we get

```
random.est2 <- c(m2$TE.random,m2$lower.random,m2$upper.random)
unlist(lapply(random.est2, meta:::backtransf,  sm="PFT", n=1/mean(1/m2$n)))
########
[1] 0.10932841 0.01376599 0.25889792

unlist(lapply(random.est2, meta:::asin2p,  n=1/mean(1/m2$n))) 
##########
[1] 0.10932841 0.01376599 0.25889792
```

Answer (score 0):

The 95%-CI's are delivered by the `summary.meta` function:

```
summary(m5)
Number of studies combined: k = 4

                     proportion           95%-CI  z  p-value
Fixed effect model       0.0775 [0.0272; 0.1449] --       --
Random effects model     0.1093 [0.0138; 0.2589] --       --

Quantifying heterogeneity:
 tau^2 = 0.0229; H = 1.78 [1.05; 3.04]; I^2 = 68.6% [9.1%; 89.2%]

Test of heterogeneity:
    Q d.f.  p-value
 9.56    3   0.0227

Details on meta-analytical method:
- Inverse variance method
- DerSimonian-Laird estimator for tau^2
- Freeman-Tukey double arcsine transformation
- Clopper-Pearson confidence interval for individual studies
```

It's fairly common to find that "mysterious values" in the output displayed at the console (or in this case in the graphical output) are actually not a part of a complex object, but are instead calculated by one  (or more) of `print.<class>`, `plot.<class>`, or a `summary.<class>` functions associated with one of the classes of the object. In this case I first looked at the help pages (where I found nothing useful) and then at the code for `getAnywhere(print.metaprop)` and getting nothing then used `m5`'s second class with `getAnywhere(print.meta)` and then saw a `summary` function being used.